# Laravel inertia vue deployed on apache subdirectory repeats subdirectory name

Tags: laravel, apache

I deployed a laravel/inertia/vue project on apache in a subdirectory of /var/www/html - let’s call it “myapp”.

On the browser: http://localhost/myapp shows as  http://localhost/myapp/myapp, repeating myapp.
The Virtual host settings on 000-default.conf are as follows:

... Original settings

```
#Settings for myapp
 Alias /myapp /var/www/html/myapp/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/myapp>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
 </Directory>
```

The .htaccess on myapp/public is the original with the following line added:
RewriteBase /myapp/

Everything works fine in myapp except, for example when showing an item

http://localhost/myapp/myapp/users/3 and press refresh on the browser, I get 404 not found because the working is is actually http://localhost/myapp/users/3 without the repeated myapp.

Is there a way to setup the deployment so it does not repeat myapp and when I type
http://localhost/myapp it actually is  http://localhost/myapp,

I have tried several suggestion by googling the problem stated but I have not been able to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the configuration needs a small adjustment to resolve this behavior.

To address the repeated subdirectory issue, please follow these steps:

1. Update .htaccess in public Directory:
   Inside the **public** directory of your Laravel application (myapp/public), ensure that the **.htaccess** file contains the following line:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This step is already mentioned in your description, but just make sure it's correctly implemented.

2. Clear Configuration Cache:

After making these changes, clear your Laravel configuration cache using the following command:

```bash
php artisan config:clear
```

3. Restart Apache:

Restart Apache to apply the changes to your virtual host configuration:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Reference:
https://lucabecchetti.medium.com/configure-laravel-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-and-with-artisan-serve-at-the-same-time-654ba0c1fd0b

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately when I add RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] to public/.htaccess I get 500 Server Error.
I was not able to get the reference example because it for older versions of laravel and apache. When I create a new project and follow the steps, I get 404.